# Filter array with subarray

Tags: arrays, angular, filter, ngfor, angular2-pipe

I'm having a problem creating a search filter, I use the * ngFor in the module and the name usually works like this:

```
(game.name.toLowerCase().includes(typed))
```

But the platforms that are coming in array only work when I put the index:

```
(game.platform[i].toLowerCase().includes(typed))
```

However this platform is dynamic and I can not use a for or something of the genre inside the filter

Json

```
[
    {
        "name":"GTA",
        "platform":[
            "xbox",
            "playstation"
        ]
    }
]
```

Component

```
<tr *ngFor="let game of (games | searchGame:SearchedText.value)">
    <td>{{game.name}}</td>
    <td>{{game.category}}</td>
    <td>{{game.platform | separator}}</td> 
    // "platform":["Playstation 4","Xbox One"]
    <td>{{game.price | currency}}</td>
    <td>{{game.quantity}}</td>
    <td>{{game.production ? 'Sim' : 'Não'}}</td>
    <td>{{game.description}}</td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-pencil icon" aria-hidden="true" (click)="staticModal.show()"></i></td>
    <td><i class="fa fa-times icon" aria-hidden="true" (click)="staticModal.show()"></i></td>
</tr>
```

Pipe

```
transform(game, typed){

    typed = typed.toLowerCase();

    return game.filter( game =>

        (game.name.toLowerCase().includes(typed)) ||

        (game.category.toLowerCase().includes(typed)) ||

        (game.platform.toLowerCase().includes(typed)) || // Error in this line

        (game.price.toLowerCase().includes(typed)) ||

        (game.quantity.toLowerCase().includes(typed)) ||

        (game.production.toLowerCase().includes(typed)) ||

        (game.description.toLowerCase().includes(typed))

    );


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, your filter is not doing what you want.

The first pipe parameter should be an array. I think just 'any' works but 'any[]' is more clean :-)

You are doing:

```
tranform(game: any,...)
```

Try this:

```
transform(game: any[], typed: string){

....

return game.filter(game => game.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(typed) > -1 ||
....
```

Further in the beginning your search token (typed) might be null or empty.
For that you should add the following to return the array unfiltered. Otherwise you will not see anything in your *ngFor.

```
if (typed == null || typed == "")
    return game;
```

Hope this helps a little.

Edit: Replace the erroring line with

```
game.filter(game => game.platforms.some(el => el.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(typed)))
```

Comment: So with the name works:
(Game.name.toLowerCase (). Includes (typed))
, But the platform that is an array only works when I place
(Game.platform [1] .toLowerCase (). Includes (typed))
I wanted for every index of this dynamic array to work as well.

Comment: Unfortunately this line generates the error:
ERROR TypeError: Can not read property 'some' of undefined
Same error as when using lowerCase without index
ERROR TypeError: Can not read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Comment: I am not sure about the wording. 'platform' or 'platform**s**'. Everything is any... In your json it is platforms and in your code it is platform without 's'

Comment: Sorry, I think it was some error when I was putting the code that came with the 's', I corrected. I'll make the code available for download, I think it's a little easier to do.

Comment: Exact file: https://github.com/HenriqueBuzin/lightning-games/blob/master/client/src/app/pipes/search/game/search-game.pipe.ts